# What are R levels?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file with R. I can read the file but I have levels when I call a variable. What are these levels and how can I remove them?
The file can be downloaded here [file](http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1314/I1.csv)

```
> data=read.csv("Documents/bet/I1.csv",sep=",")
> data$HomeTeam
  [1] Sampdoria  Verona     Cagliari   Inter      Lazio      Livorno    Napoli     Parma     
  [9] Torino     Fiorentina Chievo     Juventus   Atalanta   Bologna    Catania    Genoa     
 [17] Milan      Roma       Sassuolo   Udinese    Inter      Napoli     Torino     Fiorentina
 [25] Lazio      Livorno    Sampdoria  Udinese    Verona     Parma      Cagliari   Chievo    
 [33] Genoa      Atalanta   Bologna    Catania    Juventus   Milan      Roma       Sassuolo  
 [41] Udinese    Bologna    Chievo     Lazio      Livorno    Napoli     Parma      Sampdoria 
 [49] Torino     Inter      Genoa      Milan      Atalanta   Cagliari   Catania    Roma      
 [57] Sassuolo   Torino     Verona     Fiorentina Bologna    Catania    Napoli     Parma     
 [65] Sampdoria  Udinese    Juventus   Lazio      Chievo     Inter      Roma       Cagliari  
 [73] Milan      Atalanta   Fiorentina Genoa      Livorno    Sassuolo   Verona     Torino    
 [81] Inter      Sampdoria  Bologna    Catania    Chievo     Juventus   Lazio      Napoli    
 [89] Parma      Udinese    Atalanta   Cagliari   Fiorentina Genoa      Juventus   Livorno   
 [97] Milan      Sassuolo   Verona     Roma       Milan      Napoli     Parma      Lazio     
[105] Livorno    Sampdoria  Torino     Udinese    Verona     Bologna    Catania    Inter     
[113] Atalanta   Cagliari   Chievo     Genoa      Parma      Roma       Fiorentina Juventus  
[121] Milan      Napoli     Verona     Bologna    Livorno    Sampdoria  Sassuolo   Torino    
[129] Udinese    Roma      
20 Levels: Atalanta Bologna Cagliari Catania Chievo Fiorentina Genoa Inter Juventus ... Verona
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use [?read.csv](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to read a file, the argument `stringsAsFactors` is set by default to `TRUE`, you just need to set it to false to not get this result.  This should work:

```
data = read.csv("Documents/bet/I1.csv", sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Under the default, columns (variables) in the file that contain strings are assumed to be *factors*.  A factor is a categorical variable that can take only one of a fixed, finite set of possibilities.  Those possible categories are the levels.  You can read about factors in the R Intro manual [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Factors), and [this](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html) is another tutorial.

In addition, since you are using read.*csv*, adding the `sep=","` is redundant.  It doesn't harm anything, but the comma is taken as the separator by default.

Comment: @Donbeo Try reading [this](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html).

Comment: @Donbeo, I have edited my answer to explain factors / levels, & have included some links to references w/ more information.

Comment: Thanks! I think the second link has moved to: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html

Answer (score 2):

The presence of levels for your variable `HomeTeam` indicates that it is a factor (with 20 levels). You can specify `StringAsFactors=FALSE` argument in the `read.csv` function to remove it.