# How to compare two columns in different data.frames within R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, dataframe, compare

I am working on my first real project within R and ran into a problem. I am trying to compare 2 columns within 2 different data.frames. I tried running the code,

```
matrix1 = matrix
for (i in 1:2000){
  if(data.QW[i,1] == data.RS[i,1]){
    matrix1[i,1]== "True"
  }
  else{
    matrix1[i,1]== "False"
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Error in Ops.factor(data.QW[i,1], data.RS[i,1]) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

I think this may be because QW and RS have different row lengths. But I am trying to see where these errors might be within the different data.frames and fix them according to the source document.

I am also unsure if matrix will work for this or if I need to make it into a vector and rbind it into the matrix every time.

Any good readings on this would also be appreciated.

Comment: you could look into `merge` - you can set `all = TRUE` to merge data.frames and fill in the missing values with NA, or maybe `match` would be more suited. Also, what sort of data is in this matrix? These solutions depend on it being some sort of unique values.

Comment: That would work except I am unsure of where the missing values are. One row could be missing on one data.frame in one place and another could be missing within the other row, etc.

Comment: There is only one row being compared (row 1) so I'm not what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I missed the error - it's actually a different issue, not the dimensions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594981/getting-the-error-level-sets-of-factors-are-different-when-running-a-for-loop

Comment: The title says you are comparing two columns. But that is not what your loop is doing. It is comparing row 1 and columns 1 through 2000.

Comment: @pierreLafortune Ah, I see had those mixed up. I fixed the original code. I am still getting the same error however.

Comment: In the first line, is `matrix` an object you created or is it just the basic matrix function?

Comment: @dd3 I saw that and it's very similar to my problem but (I may be reading this wrong) that appeared to say that they had different types like a string or an int. I am pretty sure mine are both the same. Is there a way to check this within R?

Comment: @PierreLafortune it is the basic matrix function

Comment: try `levels(data.QW[,1])` and `levels(data.RS[,1])` - you may want to read about factors in R.

Comment: My crystal ball is broken. Can you post `dput(head(data.QW))` and the same for `data.RS`

Comment: Is that the matrix or the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, providing a reproducible example with the contents of the dataframe will be helpful.

Going by how the question topic sounds, it appears that you want to compare column 1 of data frame A against column 1 of data frame B and store the result in a logical vector. If that summary is accurate, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374932/comparing-two-vectors-in-an-if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Some observations:

1. Your columns, `data.QW[,1]` and `data.RS[,1]` are almost certainly factors.
2. The factors almost certainly have different set of levels (it's possible that one of the factors has a subset of the levels in the other factor). When this happens, comparisons using `==` will not work.
3. If you read your data into these data.frames using something like `read.csv(...)` any columns containing character data were converted to factors by default. You can change that behavior by setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the call to `read.csv(...)`. This is a very common problem.
4. Once you've sorted out the factors/levels problem, you can avoid the loop by using, simply: `data.QW[1:2000,1]==data.RW[1:2000,1]`. This will create a vector of length 2000 containing all the comparisons. No loop needed. Of course this assumes that both data.frames have at least 2000 rows.

Here's an example of item 2:

```
x <- as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5],3))   # has levels: A, B, C, D, E
y <- as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3],5))   # has levels: A, B, C
y==x
# Error in Ops.factor(y, x) : level sets of factors are different
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function `compare` compares data.frames or matrices `a,b` to find row matches of `a` in `b`. It returns the first row position in `b` which matches (after some internal sorting required to speed thinks up). Rows in `a` which have no match in `b` will have a return value of `0`. Should handle numeric, character and factor column types and mixtures thereof (the latter for `data.frames` only). Check the example below the function definition.

```
compare<-function(a,b){

    #################################################
    if(dim(a)[2]!=dim(b)[2]){
        stop("\n Matrices a and b have different number of columns!")
    }
    if(!all(sapply(a, class)==sapply(b, class))){
        stop("\n Matrices a and b have incomparable column data types!")    
    }
    #################################################
    if(is.data.frame(a)){
        i <- sapply(a, is.factor)
        a[i] <- lapply(a[i], as.character)
    }
    if(is.data.frame(b)){
        i <- sapply(b, is.factor)
        b[i] <- lapply(b[i], as.character)
    }
    len1<-dim(a)[1]
    len2<-dim(b)[1]
    ord1<-do.call(order,as.data.frame(a))
    a<-a[ord1,]
    ord2<-do.call(order,as.data.frame(b))
    b<-b[ord2,]     
    #################################################
    found<-rep(0,len1)  
    dims<-dim(a)[2]
    do_dims<-c(1:dim(a)[2]) 
    at<-1
    for(i in 1:len1){
        for(m in do_dims){
            while(b[at,m]<a[i,m]){
                at<-(at+1)      
                if(at>len2){break}              
            }
            if(at>len2){break}
            if(b[at,m]>a[i,m]){break}
            if(m==dims){found[i]<-at}
        }
        if(at>len2){break}
    }
    #################################################
    found<-found[order(ord1)]
    found<-ord2[found]
    return(found)

}
# example data sets:
ncols<-10
nrows<-1E4
a <- matrix(sample(LETTERS,size = (ncols*nrows), replace = T), ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows)
b <- matrix(sample(LETTERS,size = (ncols*nrows), replace = T), ncol = ncols, nrow = nrows)
b <- rbind(a,b) # example of b containing a
b <- b[sample(dim(b)[1],dim(b)[1],replace = F),] 
found<-compare(a,b)

a<-as.data.frame(a) # = conversion to factors
b<-as.data.frame(b) # = conversion to factors
found<-compare(a,b)
```