# Print pandas data frame for reproducible example (equivalent to dput in R)

Tags: pandas

Lately I'm constantly finding myself asking questions in `Pandas` which depend on data that I'm using , so far it takes me quite a while to create a data frame with similarity to my data (reproducible data frame) so that SO users could easily copy it to their machine.

I would prefer to find a convenient way so i could just print my small DF within my question, and other users could easily collect it, hence creating it with minimum effort.

In `R` I'm used to print a small sample of my data within the `dput` function in the console, and then printing the output within my question (example):
[Getting the error "level sets of factors are different" when running a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594981/getting-the-error-level-sets-of-factors-are-different-when-running-a-for-loop)

I've noticed this explanation, but i don't think its suitable for printing a sample of data for other SO users:
[Python's equivalent for R's dput() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418895/pythons-equivalent-for-rs-dput-function)

Is there an equivalent method in Pandas for doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If binary data is OK for you, you can use the `pickle` library. It usually allows to serialize and deserialize arbitraty objects (on condition that their class definition is provided, which is true for dataframes, if pandas is installed).

If you need a human-readable format, you can create a Python dictionary from your dataframe with `df_dict = df.to_dict()`, and print this dictionary (to look at it and maybe copy-paste), or dump it to a JSON string.

When you want to convert a dict back to pandas, use `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)`.

A minimal example of decoding and encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 3}})
print(df.to_dict())
```

which results in the `{'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 3}}` copy-able object.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: This was helpful thanks for sharing. But I'm discovering that there's a limit to the size of the dictionary. I'm using mtcars which is only 32x11 and I had a cut off a couple columns to make it work. Does that sound right to you?