# Python - Pandas Dataframe Table/Column Structure

Tags: python, pandas

1. I Have a table like below:
   [image]
2. I converted the table as I needed like this:
   [image]
3. But I want to categorize the values with the column names like this (example of result needed):
   [image]

Here's my code:

```py
inv_power = inv_power.set_axis(['Timestamp', 'Time', 'INV1','INV2','INV3','INV4','INV5','INV6','INV7','INV8','INV9','INV10', 'INV11','INV12','INV13','INV14','INV15','INV16','INV17','INV18','INV19','INV20'], axis=1) 

inv_power = inv_power.replace('', np.nan).set_index('Timestamp').stack().reset_index(name='AC_Power').drop('level_1', 1)
```

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample of the data so that we can try to help you out. Images do not help as much as the data will.

Comment: okay, edited with some lines of code

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data such that I can copy it and run it on my own end. A subset of the main dataframe would be enough. What you've posted above is not enough, since `name 'inv_power' is not defined`. [Edit your answer with something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451083/4112751).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
inv_power['Slot No.'] = pd.np.tile(inverter, len(inv_power) // len(inverter)).tolist() + inverter[:len(inv_power)%len(inverter)]
```