# r - levels added to dataframe, why?

Tags: r, rbind, levels

This post is to better understand how "levels" work in R. Indeed, other answers were not fully explanatory (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314318/what-are-r-levels)).

Consider the following short script, where I calculate the RMSE of each column of a random dataframe `df` and store the value as a row of a new dataframe `bestcombo`

```
df = as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*1000, 1, .5), nrow = 10, ncol=5))

#generate empty dataframe and assign col names
bestcombo = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
colnames(bestcombo) = c("RMSE", "Row Number")

#for each col of df calculate RMSE and store together with col name
for (i in 1:5){
  RMSE = sqrt(mean(df[,i] ^ 2))
  row_num = i

  row = as.data.frame(cbind( RMSE, toString(row_num) ))
  colnames(row) = c("RMSE", "Row Number")
  bestcombo = rbind(bestcombo, row)
}
```

The problem is that "Levels" are generated. Why?

```
bestcombo$RMSE
             RMSE              RMSE              RMSE              RMSE              RMSE 
0.547722557505166 0.774596669241483 0.707106781186548 0.836660026534076 0.707106781186548 
Levels: 0.547722557505166 0.774596669241483 0.707106781186548 0.836660026534076

bestcombo$RMSE[1]
             RMSE 
0.547722557505166 
Levels: 0.547722557505166 0.774596669241483 0.707106781186548 0.836660026534076
```

Why is this happening and how to avoid it? Is this due to a wrong use of rbind()?

This also produces other problems. For example, the order function does not work.

```
bestcombo[order(bestcombo$RMSE),]

               RMSE Random Vector
1 0.547722557505166             1
2 0.774596669241483             2
3 0.707106781186548             3
5 0.707106781186548             5
4 0.836660026534076             4
```

Comment: Because of this: `as.data.frame(cbind( RMSE, toString(row_num) ))` which is an somewhat common idiom for creating data frames that is pretty inadvisable. Just use `data.frame()` instead. `cbind` is coercing things to a single type, character.

Comment: Also, you really want to be using `as.character`, not `toString`. The name is a tad misleading, if you read the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. However, even removing "as" from as.data.frame the "levels" still remain. And the ordering still does not work.

Comment: See my answer below for more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something more like this:

```
#for each col of df calculate RMSE and store together with col name
for (i in 1:5){
    RMSE = sqrt(mean(df[,i] ^ 2))
    row_num = i

    row = data.frame(RMSE = RMSE, `Row Number` = as.character(row_num) )
    #colnames(row) = c("RMSE", "Row Number")
    bestcombo = rbind(bestcombo, row)
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to add the column names in a second line, you do this:

```
for (i in 1:5){
    RMSE = sqrt(mean(df[,i] ^ 2))
    row_num = i

    row = data.frame(RMSE,as.character(row_num) )
    colnames(row) = c("RMSE", "Row Number")
    bestcombo = rbind(bestcombo, row)
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll add that while it wasn't the focus of your question, growing data frames by `rbind`ind rows one at a time like this will begin to incur a *significant* speed penalty once the data frame gets to be reasonably large.